# Display Document Library from Hub Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepointdocumentlibrary

Other than using the "embed" webpart, is there a way to display a document library from a Hub site on an associated site?

Or a way to change the look of the embedded library so that the header commands are not visible or the view defaults to its own view?

I want to get rid of the "new", "upload", "edit" headers but still allow filtering.

[image: embedded document library]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to display a document library from a hub site on an associated site except for the Embed web part.

If you only need to display files from an associated site, you could consider to use the "Highlighted Content" web part on a modern page.

It allows you to pick up contents, then filter by content type, file type, and managed properties. You can use the "path" managed property to only get documents from a specific library (Path Begins with {library url}).